# EF4 code first adding items not very clear to me

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I don't understand why code first does not add a new item to the collection until after calling savechanges. I installed EF4.1 from NuGet (4.1.10331.0). I created the following example:

```
public class TinyItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TinyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<TinyItem> Items { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx1 = new TinyContext())
        {
            ListItems(ctx1, "Start");

            ctx1.Items.Add(new TinyItem { Name = "Test1" });
            ListItems(ctx1, "After add");

            ctx1.SaveChanges();
            ListItems(ctx1, "After commit");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void ListItems(TinyContext ctx, string label="")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=========================================");
        Console.WriteLine(label);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Items.Local: {0}", ctx.Items.Local.Count));
        foreach (var item in ctx.Items.Local)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", item.Id, item.Name));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Items: {0}", ctx.Items.Count()));
        foreach (var item in ctx.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", item.Id, item.Name));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("=========================================");
    }
```

First I added one record to the database. Then I ran this and these are the results:

```
    =========================================
    Start
    Items.Local: 0
    Items: 1
    4 = Test1
    =========================================
    =========================================
    After add
    Items.Local: 2
    4 = Test1
    0 = Test1
    Items: 1
    4 = Test1
    =========================================
    =========================================
    After commit
    Items.Local: 2
    4 = Test1
    5 = Test1
    Items: 2
    4 = Test1
    5 = Test1
    =========================================
```

My questions are:
- Why does the first call to ctx.Items.Local give my zero items?
- Why does the list of ctx.Items not contain the just added item before I called SaveChanges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the first call to
>   ctx.Items.Local give my zero items?

Because EF hasn't loaded any items from the database(or you haven't added any). Hence it is not tracking any items yet. That is shown as `0`.

Here's the msdn description for `Local`

> Returns ObservableCollection that
>   represents entities of the set that
>   are currently being tracked by the
>   context and have not been marked as
>   Deleted. Accessing the Local property
>   never causes a query to be sent to the
>   database. This property is usually
>   used after a query has already been
>   executed.

---

> Why does the list of ctx.Items not
>   contain the just added item before I
>   called SaveChanges?

When you refer `ctx.Items` it will be fetched from database. Since there is only 1 item (you haven't called the `SaveChanges()` method) in the database it shows the item(s) in the database.

Comment: About the last question: it's about the collection BEFORE the SaveChanges, there the item is not added (the "After add" section).

Comment: Ok, but why doesn't the collection represent the current Session/Transaction? It now represents the current Database and I dont't care about that.

Comment: @John `ctx.Items.Local` is an `ObservableCollection` but `ctx.Items` is not a collection. Its the `IQueryable` in EF. So when you execute against that it will query the database.

Comment: Thanks, it is an explanation, but I still think it is strange behaviour.